# Comparing Element.value to number is giving unexpected results

Tags: javascript, html, css, operators

It calculates / compares only the first digit on all three numbers. I think, it is taking the input values as string/text. could someone help me in this pls..

It takes the value as numbers but it is considering it as text.

```js
function chkcnd() {
  var fnumber = document.getElementById("fnumber").value;
  var snumber = document.getElementById("snumber").value;
  var tnumber = document.getElementById("tnumber").value;

  if (fnumber >= snumber && fnumber >= tnumber) {
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "First Number is Big";
  } else if (snumber >= fnumber && snumber >= tnumber) {
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Second Number is Big";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Third Number is Big";
  }
}

document.getElementById("btn-snd").onclick = chkcnd;

function clear() {
  document.getElementById("fnumber").value = "";
  document.getElementById("snumber").value = "";
  document.getElementById("tnumber").value = "";
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>
      <label for="fnumber">Enter First number</label>
    </th>
    <td>
      <input type="number" name="fnumber" id="fnumber">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>
      <label for="snumber">Enter First number</label>
    </th>
    <td>
      <input type="number" name="snumber" id="snumber">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>
      <label for="tnumber">Enter First number</label>
    </th>
    <td>
      <input type="number" name="tnumber" id="tnumber">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th><label for="Result">Result</label></th>
    <td>
      <p id="result"></p>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td> <button type="button" id="btn-snd">Submil</button> </td>
    <td> <button type="button" id="btn-cnd">Cancel</button> </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Use the built in API `valueAsNumber` which doesn't require the string to number conversion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's probably because your fsnumber, snumber and tnumber are stored in html as strings. You just need to convert those numbers to integers. Obviously add some logic to check if it succeeded in converting before using the variables further.

```
  var fnumber = parseInt(document.getElementById("fnumber").value);
  var snumber = parseInt(document.getElementById("snumber").value);
  var tnumber = parseInt(document.getElementById("tnumber").value);
```

Comment: everything is stored in HTML as strings, also as noted in the comment on the question you can simply use `document.getElementById("fnumber").valueAsNumber`

Comment: And please don't forget the second paramenter of `parseInt` while it is optional [it does **not** default to 10](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt#description)!

Comment: Thank you everyone for your response.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert all the values to a number before comparing them by using the `+` sign.
I've edited your code in the below snippet. It should work now.

```js
  function chkcnd() {
    var fnumber = document.getElementById("fnumber").value;
    var snumber = document.getElementById("snumber").value;
    var tnumber = document.getElementById("tnumber").value;

    if (+fnumber >= +snumber && +fnumber >= +tnumber) {
      document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "First Number is Big";
    } else if (+snumber >= +fnumber && +snumber >= +tnumber) {
      document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Second Number is Big";
    } else {
      document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Third Number is Big";
    }
  }

document.getElementById("btn-snd").onclick = chkcnd;

function clear() {
  document.getElementById("fnumber").value = "";
  document.getElementById("snumber").value = "";
  document.getElementById("tnumber").value = "";
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>
      <label for="fnumber">Enter First number</label>
    </th>
    <td>
      <input type="number" name="fnumber" id="fnumber">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>
      <label for="snumber">Enter First number</label>
    </th>
    <td>
      <input type="number" name="snumber" id="snumber">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>
      <label for="tnumber">Enter First number</label>
    </th>
    <td>
      <input type="number" name="tnumber" id="tnumber">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th><label for="Result">Result</label></th>
    <td>
      <p id="result"></p>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td> <button type="button" id="btn-snd">Submil</button> </td>
    <td> <button type="button" id="btn-cnd">Cancel</button> </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Or use the built in API `valueAsNumber` which doesn't require conversion.

Answer (score 0):

Just update that part:

```js
  var fnumber = parseFloat(document.getElementById("fnumber").value);
  var snumber = parseFloat(document.getElementById("snumber").value);
  var tnumber = parseFloat(document.getElementById("tnumber").value);
```

Comment: see all the comments on all the other answers (.valueAsNumber,  etc)